# Switch statement task at Uni

Tags: switch-statement

I have this switch statement question at uni and I kind of sorted out how to do it except the very first case. It is about a number less than 0. This is the only bit I can't figure out. Have a look.

Write a C program that repeatedly asks the user to enter an integer 
number.

- If the number is negative then the program should print out 
  the message “BYE” and stop
- If the number is either 0 or 1 then it should print out “VERY 
  LOW”
- If the number is either 2 or 3 it should print out “LOW”
- If the number is either 4 or 5 it should print out “MEDIUM”
- If the number is either 6 or 7 it should print out “HIGH”
- If the number is either 8 or 9 it should print out “VERY HIGH”
- Any other number should cause the program to output the 
  message “Input a value between 0 and 9 only”
  Use a switch statement inside the loop to select the appropriate 
  message to print.

This is my piece of code and I'm trying to figure out the first case without a name.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int value;

        printf("Enter a value: ");
        scanf(" %i",&value);

        switch ( value )
        {
            case : printf("BYE\n"); break;
        case 0:
        case 1: printf("VERY LOW\n"); break;
        case 2:
        case 3: printf("LOW\n"); break;
        case 4:
            case 5: printf("MEDIUM\n"); break;
        case 6:
        case 7: printf("HIGH\n"); break;
        case 8:
            case 9: printf("VERY HIGH\n"); break; 
        default: printf("Input a value between 0 and 9 only\n"); break;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There's only two billion numbers less than zero that fit in an `int` data type. Start typing! Or give up on your strange fixation with using `switch`.

Comment: But this is a question which comes up on the exam @Blindy

Comment: Then you misunderstood the question, in which case you'll fail it anyway. Again I say, give up your strange fixation with `switch`.

Comment: How would you do it then? Instead of being harsh, explain what's wrong and how I should do it. You behave like a kid right now.

Comment: If you want to check if a number is negative, simply do that. `if(value<0){printf("BYE\n");return 0;}`

Comment: That's what I've done later on but won't this be a wrong answer on the exam? I'll be using if statement linked with switch statement.